# Retrieving unable to convert yaml to json error kubernetes yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-pod

I have following YAML I am creating two pods in one YAML file.

```
  apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
       name: test
       labels:
          app: test
    spec:
       containers:
         - name: test
           image: test:latest
           command: ["sleep"]
           args: ["infinity"]

    kind: Pod
    metadata:
       name: testing1
       labels:
          app: testing1
    spec:
       containers:
         - name: testing1
           image: testing1:latest
           command: ["sleep"]
           args: ["infinity"]
```

I am retrieving the following error. I checked the code on lint too, but I am unable to solve it.

```
error parsing pipeline.YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: line 27 could not find expected ':;
```

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Under `containers:`, do you literally have `-name` (with no space), and then the lines under that at the same indentation as the `-`?  There needs to be a space after `-`, and then `image:` and the other settings need to be aligned with `name:` (two steps more indentation).

Comment: @DavidMaze, I have updated the code it was a typo mistake while doing indentation on stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: Which line is line 27?  Are you sure you have the indentation correct?  Are you specifying `kind:` and the other fields twice on the same object?

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you for your help its working now they were two issues in the code first I need to specify --- between the two pods and second I had to specify apiversion for the second pod

Comment: This error is why I personally hate yaml

Comment: @Mazia please consider posting your solution as an answer for better visibility, so other who encounter similar issue might find your answer helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: test
   labels:
      app: test
spec:
   containers:
   - name: test
     image: test:latest
     command: ["sleep"]
     args: ["infinity"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: testing1
   labels:
      app: testing1
spec:
   containers:
   - name: testing1
     image: testing1:latest
     command: ["sleep"]
     args: ["infinity"]
```

There was an indentation error under containers section and you have to separate the pod definition by `---`  and also you had to add the apiVersion.